# How to write a code for this pattern? (C++)

Tags: loops, design-patterns

This is the pattern i want to make in C++ using nested for loop.

2 4 6 8

3 7 11 15

4 10 16 22

I tried it but unfortunately failed to make the perfect logic for it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <8; j=j+2)
    {
        cout << i + j + 2;

    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

well, first row for the pattern is working fine but not the other two and i don't know what to do to make it perfect.

Comment: You tried?  Lets see it

Comment: Edit your post to include what you already have so we can help you reevaluate your logic and help you fix your existing code to work. This isn't chegg :(

Comment: well i know it is very basic but i m new to c++ so..

{

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

 {
  for (int j = 0; j <8; j=j+2)

  {

   cout << i + j + 2;

   
  }

  cout << endl;

 }

Comment: Can you edit your post and put it there instead of the comments.

Comment: Good one , let me try

Comment: The first iteration will increase with `+2`, the second will `+3` and last but not the least will increase by `+6` each time. What is actual problem? How would you go about taking input?